# Data bleeding between tests when using xUnit/EFCore/sqlite in memory

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have a Blazor application that I'm trying to write unit tests for. I'm having issues when accessing data in the in-memory database. When I run tests independently of each other they complete successfully. When run in parallel, they conflict either giving me incorrect results or throwing because I'm adding the same test entity

I'm using the SqliteInMemory helper class to simulate an EF Core db context in memory, then filling out with the entities I need.

```
public ServiceContext SetUpContext()
{
    DbContextOptions<ServiceContext> options =
        SqliteInMemory.CreateOptions<ServiceContext>();
    var context = new ServiceContext(options, new NullLogger<ServiceContext>());
    context.CreateEmptyViaDelete();
    context.SaveChanges();
    return context;
}
```

This is then called at the start of each test to get the context and then I add in relevant data to test.

```
context.MyEntities.Add(entity1);
context.MyEntities.Add(entity2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This issue usually hits here. I get errors stating that the entity can't be added, which I'm fairly confident is due to the content already being in there.

> The instance of entity type 'MyEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: entity1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

Reading through the library, it seems that it's creating each db in memory, but when other methods try to create a new db, they're getting the same context and I can't figure out why.

```
 SqliteConnection sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection(new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder()
  {
    DataSource = ":memory:"
  }.ToString());
  sqliteConnection.Open();
```

Things I've tried:

- switching the dataSource to "file:" + Guid.newGuid()

  - This errored stating that another process had locked the file. Nothing was written to the file.
- switching the dataSource to "file:" + Guid.newGuid() + "?mode=memory"

  - No effect
- Moving the placement of the context to the class constructor (which should be run before each test)

  - No effect
- Implementing using statements on the context around all tests.

  - No effect

I'm running out of things to try. Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out the reason?

Comment: Same problem here any solution?